# Amplo demais? Qual o problema desta pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

A pergunta "[Como acessar informações de um arquivo .torrent?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60666/como-acessar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-arquivo-torrent)" foi fechada porque estava ampla demais e mesmo depois do AP informar a linguagem não foi reaberta. Passou 1 semana e ele fez uma outra [pergunta idêntica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62621/como-pegar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-arquivo-torrent) e que também foi fechada como ampla demais (mesmo que desta vez tenha já informado a linguagem PHP).

Ao meu ver, esta nova deveria ser excluída, editar a antiga incluindo as novas informações e tentar reabrir. Mas parece que não foi bem recebida segundo as análises recentes.

**Minha pergunta é:** qual o problema? Por que continua ampla demais? Eu mesmo havia feito testes em um código que extrai informações de um arquivo *.torrent*, então julgo haver uma resposta clara para isso e não amplo.

E se esse é o tipo de pergunta que deve procurar no Google (segundo [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60666/como-acessar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-arquivo-torrent?noredirect=1#comment128012_60666)), então por que existe o *SOpt*? Eu penso que este tipo de pergunta agrega conteúdo ao site, como é um dos nossos objetivos.

Comment: Concordo. Essa história de mandar os outros procurar no Google é a maior palhaçada, é a mesma coisa que você ser o vendedor de uma loja de roupas daí entra um cliente e diz: "Gostaria de comprar uma roupa para mim.", daí você responde: "Na loja do lado tem umas bem legais."

Comment: @Math "A loja do lado tem a roupa que você quer, mas os vendedores só falam Inglês" :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A pergunta foi reaberta. Não é ampla demais, é possível responder dentro dos parâmetros e do espaço disponível no site. Também deixei um comentário para o usuário que parecia confuso sobre as regras do site em relação a conteúdos encontráveis no Google. Citando [meu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60666/como-acessar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-arquivo-torrent?noredirect=1#comment128039_60666):

> O fato de a resposta existir no Google não quer dizer que ela não tenha espaço aqui. A não ser que a pergunta seja ampla demais (por exemplo, caso a resposta seja a documentação completa de uma ferramenta) ou tenha outro tipo de problema. O simples fato de haver respostas em outros lugares não invalida a pergunta aqui.